# Remove list element without mutation

Tags: python, list

Assume you have a list

```
>>> m = ['a','b','c']
```

I'd like to make a new list `n` that has everything except for a given item in `m` (for example the item `'a'`).  However, when I use

```
>>> m.remove('a')
>>> m
m = ['b', 'c']
```

the original list is mutated (the value `'a'` is removed from the original list).  Is there a way to get a new list sans-`'a'` without mutating the original? So I mean that `m` should still be `[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]`, and I will get a *new* list, which has to be `[ 'b', 'c' ]`.

Comment: What do you want the end result to be? You can copy m into a new list with m[:]

Comment: You mean... to remove something from a list without changing the list?  Or do you mean like replacing an item in a list with some sort of null representation so the indices don't change?

Comment: yeah, i mean to remove something without changing the list

Comment: you mean `my_var = m[0]`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to create a new list without a given element, instead of changing the original list. One way is to use a list comprehension:

```
m = ['a', 'b', 'c']
n = [x for x in m if x != 'a']
```

`n` is now a copy of `m`, but without the `'a'` element.

Another way would of course be to copy the list first

```
m = ['a', 'b', 'c']
n = m[:]
n.remove('a')
```

If removing a value by index, it is even simpler

```
n = m[:index] + m[index+1:]
```

Comment: In this specific instance I feel it's worth mentioning if you want a copy of the the list except for the 0th element you can slice it with `m[1:]`.

Comment: True, but I read the question as it is desired to remove an element by value, not by index. Still, a good point!

Comment: It's only useful if you know for sure it's the first element in the list you don't want but I think it'll be useful for future readers to illustrate how list slicing works.

Comment: I would like to add that the first and second approach have different behaviour if the value is not unique in the list. The first would remove all occurrences of the value, whereas the second would only remove the first occurrence.

Answer (score 17):

There is a simple way to do that using built-in function :filter .

Here is ax example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = filter(lambda x: x != 3, a)
```

Comment: This is golden. Have my upvote. Can't believe I was running `list.pop()` in a loop to achieve this. My indexes got so messed up.

Comment: The filter approach does not work.  remove only removes 1 element, while the filter recipe will remove all elements equal to the given value.   if the list is `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]`, then `remove(x,1)` will result in `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]` while the filter recipe will result in `[2]`

Answer (score 8):

If the order is unimportant, you can use set (besides, the removal seems to be fast in sets):

```
list(set(m) - set(['a']))
```

This will remove duplicate elements from your original list though

Answer (score 4):

We can do it via built-in copy() function for list;
However, should assign a new name for the copy;

```
m = ['a','b','c']
m_copy=m.copy()
m_copy.remove('a')

print (m)
```

['a', 'b', 'c']

```
print(m_copy)
```

['b', 'c']

Answer (score 2):

We can do it without using in built remove function and also without creating new list variable

Code:

```
# List m
m = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Updated list m, without creating new list variable
m = [x for x in m if x != a]

print(m)
```

output

```
>>> ['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list without the offending element with a list-comprehension. This will preserve the value of the original list.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[s for s in l if s != 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to list comprehension is numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(numpy.remove(a, a.index(3)))
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: This only works for me with ```numpy.delete(a, a.index(3))``` now

Answer (score 0):

The question is useful as I sometimes have a list that I use throughout my given script but I need to at a certain step to apply a logic on a subset of the list elements. In that case I found it useful to use the same list but only exclude the needed element for that individual step, without the need to create a totally new list with a different name. For this you can use either:

1. list comprehension: say you have `l=['a','b','c']` to exclude b, you can have `[x for x in l if x!='b']`
2. set [only if order is unimortant]: `list(set(l) - set(['b']))`, pay attention here that you pass `'b'` as list `['b']`